# iOS in-app purchases not being recognized for some users. What could be the issue? This one really as me stumped

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

I have four apps on the apple store that have in-app purchases to "ugprade" the app to a "pro version" which unlocks additional features.  But I am getting e-mails from a lot of users saying that the app is not recognizing their purchase after they buy it, and yes I do have a restore purchases button, but when users click on that it doesn't fix their issue.

I gave them the whole spiel about making sure they are signed into the same apple ID to make the purchase, restart their device, etc but that doesn't help any of the users. Some have even brought their iPhones into apple store or called apple, but they weren't able to help.

**What really has me stumped is this is only happening to about 25% of users. On my iPad and iPhone the purchases and restore buttons are working flawlessly.** This seems to be happening exclusively on iOS 10.x.x. ***It does happen to users making the purchase for the first time, but it also happens to users who have purchased the upgrade in the past and had it working, but then suddenly the app forgets their purchase when they installed a newer version of the app.***

I know not sharing code here is frowned-upon but I have poured over my code day in and day out trying to find any problems with it but I can't. It completely follows everything apple has written about implementing in-app purchases. And that also doesn't explain why it works on my iPhone flawlessly but not on some other people's iPhones. If it works fine on mine it should work fine on all, right?

Just hoping someone here may have had similar issues and found a fix.

Comment: (1) Have you asked someone with the issue to actually delete the app, reinstall it, and *then* restore purchases? (2) You state it works on your personal devices. Are you using *your* Apple ID and the AppStore, or made up Apple IDs and the iTC Sandbox? (3) The code I'd be interested in seeing is your error handling, which from the sounds of things hasn't needed to be there for *you* but should be working for those with the issue. In fact, not just error handling, but *all* user feedback from your app - not StoreKit.

Comment: (1) Yes I've had several people delete the app and reinstall it, then restore purchases. It didn't help.

(2) I'm using my own apple ID, no made up stuff.

Comment: I get how hard this is then. Have you tried anything with #3? It seems like *something* is going on that *maybe* errors (connection, time out, anything) might give you something. Maybe - probably not but maybe - sandbox testing would see it. And yes, (1) I haven't had any issues with non-consumable IAPs and (2) you haven't shown any code. On the latter, even the best of us can get "blind" to a code error that someone else may give light to. My experience here at SO - all on Swift questions - says it a large group that it might be worthwhile to post your MVCE code, even it takes two hours.

Comment: Should I post just the code that handles the purchases or should I post the whole app code?

Comment: At this point - I'm the only one commenting in 2 days - it sounds like it's me and you. (Not the purpose of SO but that's not always the point.) I say post your IAP code. Maybe an answer or a more specific question will come of it. (I deleted an answer 2 days ago because the correct thing was a different answer that involved a RADR.)